# What ClearCase plugin to use with Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins, integration, add-in, clearcase

At work I have to use ClearCase v7.0.1.2 and ClearQuest v7.0.1.0 with Visual Studio 2008 SP1. Am running on a Windows XP SP2 box.

I've done some searching but not found an official installer yet, can anyone advise (provide a link to) on the best plugin/addin to install for Visual Studio 2008 integration?

Thanks

Comment: Just added another technical note to explain why ccvsiinterfaces.dll and ccvsisearchtoolwin.dll are missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official instructions are in this [IBM page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=727&uid=swg24017991)

- [CC-CQ-VS2008.zip (32 bits)](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/clearcase/7.0.1/VS2008_support/CC-CQ-VS2008.zip)
- [CC-CQ-VS2008.zip (64 bits)](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/clearcase/7.0.1/VS2008_support/CC-CQ-64_BIT-VS2008.rar)

Process:

- Download the appropriate package from the FTP link below to your ClearCase, CCRC or ClearQuest host.
- Decompress the archive to a temp location.
- Follow the instructions (extracted from the archive) outlined for ClearCase (CC_INSTRUCTIONS.txt) or ClearQuest (CQ_INSTRUCTIONS.txt) or ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC_INSTRUCTIONS.txt) to complete the steps to enable the feature integrations.

Extract: (ClearCase 32 bits)

In order to **register ClearCase 7.0.1 with Visual Studio 2008**, the following steps are required:

1. Install Visual Studio 2008
2. Install Rational ClearCase v7.0.1 or later
   Note:  Be sure to select the VS.NET integration when installing ClearCase.
3. Download and extract the contents of `CC-CQ-VS2008.zip` to a temp location (for example `C:\Temp`) on the ClearCase host with Visual Studio 2008 installed.
   There will be 6 files extracted:

   - `ccvsisearchtoolwin_VS2008.reg`,
   - `ccvsiwanservice_VS2008.reg`,
   - `reg_VS2008.bat`,
   - `CCRC_INSTRUCTIONS.txt`,
   - `CC_INSTRUCTIONS.txt`,
   - `CQ_INSTRUCTIONS.txt`.
4. Search for a file named `ccvsisearchtoolwin.DLL` on the ClearCase host to obtain the path where this file resides.
   Note:  The default location is `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Rational\ClearCase\CCVSI\bin`
5. Edit the `ccvsisearchtoolwin_VS2008.reg` registry file you just downloaded using a text editor (for example Wordpad) and search for the following string:
   `"CodeBase"="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Rational\\ClearCase\\CCVSI\\bin\\ccvsisearchtoolwin.DLL"`.
   Verify that this path matches the installation path identified in step #4.  If the path does not match, modify the path to match.
   Note:  Keep the double back slashes, this is expected.
6. Next, search for the following string in the file `ccvsisearchtoolwin_VS2008.reg`:
   `"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Rational\\ClearCase\\CCVSI\\bin"`.
   Verify that this path matches the installation path identified in step #4.  If the path does not match, modify the path to match.  Save and close the file  `ccvsisearchtoolwin_VS2008.reg`.
7. Next, search for a file named `ccvsiwanservice.DLL` on the ClearCase host to obtain the path where this file resides.
   Note:  The default location is `C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\CCRCVSI\WanPackage`.
8. Edit the `ccvsiwanservice_VS2008.reg` registry file you just downloaded using a text editor and search for the following string:
   `"CodeBase"="C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\Rational\\CCRCVSI\\WanPackage\\ccvsiwanservice.DLL"`.
   Verify that this path matches the installation path identified in step #7.  If the path does not match, modify the path to match.
9. Next, search for the following string in the file `ccvsiwanservice_VS2008.reg`:
   `"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\Rational\\CCRCVSI\\WanPackage"`.
   Verify that this path matches the installation path identified in step #7.  If the path does not match, modify the path to match.  Save and close the file `ccvsiwanservice_VS2008.reg`.
10. Next, edit the batch file named `reg_VS2008.bat` with a text editor and fill in the 8 different variables based on the selections provided.  Save and close the file.
11. Execute the batch file in its current location (double click the batch file) to register the dlls and configure the integration feature with Visual Studio 2008.

---

Note: be aware of:

- [technical note 21316693](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21316693):

> ClearCase and Visual Studio 2008 integration missing ccvsiwanservice.dll
>
> If CCRC has not been installed on the host, this file is unavailable.
>
> Resolving the problem
>
> If you are not going to use CCRC on the host, the workaround would be to edit the `reg_VS2008.bat` file and set CCRC_for_VS in the bat file to 0, which means it won't set `ccWAN` in that bat file.

- [technical note 21295269](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21295269)

Cause

> The files that are required to setup the integration are missing if ClearCase has not been installed with the Visual Studio integration options.
>
> The README indicated that Visual Studio 2008 could be installed before ClearCase and made no reference of the integration option when installing ClearCase.

Follow the instructions in [technote 1259189](http://ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21259189) to integrate ClearCase and Visual Studio.

Note: You will need to select the Visual Studio 2005 integration option.

Once ClearCase is reinstalled with the Visual Studio integration files, the [Visual Studio 2008 integration procedure for ClearCase 7.0.1 will work as expected](http://ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg24017991).

Comment: Excellent response, I will try this and see how I go!

Comment: Hmm my computer is missing files: ccvsiinterfaces.dll, ccvsisearchtoolwin.DLL, ccvsiwanservice.DLL they should be in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Rational\ClearCase\CCVSI\bin yet they are not. I searched the whole PC and they are nowhere. I think I read somewhere when ClearCase is installed there is an option to include Visual Studio support maybe this was not selected? The operations team did the install so I don't know, will escalate.

Comment: VonC we have switch at work as a policy to CCRC but now I am missing the ccvsiwanservice.dll and can't find it, any help on resolving this one? I cannot find it anywhere on my computer

Comment: @m3ntat: see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21316693 and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=332561&tstart=105